# Is it possible to build a labeledPoint in Spark from a "feature matrix" rather than a feature vector?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm working on a classification problem in Spark where the dataset of examples are built upon a historical set of features.
The problem is related to network management with the aim to discover faults during the day-by-day running of devices.For istance every DeviceID has a time-series of "vectors" representing its daily operation. Is it possible to build a "feature matrix" in order to have a "labeledpoint" based on a historical features and not on a simple feature vector? (Sorry for my english...)

Comment: What you are asking isn't clear. If you have LabeledPoint RDD, you can convert it into a Matrix. There is many answers that covers this part already.

Answer (score 0):

**No**: Because the signature of the `LabeledPoint` constructor is clear:

```
new LabeledPoint(label: Double, features: Vector)
```

It takes a `Vector` not `Matrix`.

**Yes**: Every matrix can be easily represented as 1D vector and there is not a single algorithm which cares about the meaning of a particular feature (some consider declared types though).